# Xclip command works in shell but not in keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xdotool, xclip

I have to paste my email often during the day, and typing it is time consuming. That is why I am searching for a way to do this with a button press. 
The following command works to place my mail on my clipboard when used in bash:

```
echo "lorem@ipsum.com" | xclip -sel clip
```

And after running it I can successfully go to another application like Firefox and press ctrl+v to paste it.
When I use this command with a shortcut it doesn't work however.
[image: example shortcut]

Any Idea how to make this work?

P.S.
I also tried 'xdotool' by setting a keyboard shortcut to:

```
xdotool type 'l' 'o' 'r' 'e' 'm' '@' 'i' 'p' 's' 'u' 'm' '.' 'c' 'o' 'm'
```

And some variations of that but all of them are too laggy and only start printing halfway through the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think you might want to combine the two like this:

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.5; xdotool type "$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)"'
```

for just making a keybinding to selecting the text. You need to make sure that the meta-keys in the binding are not pressed when it tries to run the command (`xdotool` creates keypresses, and it won't release the Ctrl key for you).

Second, by default `xclip` selects `XA_Primary` buffer rather than the `XA_CLIPBOARD`. So you should pass clipboard as the selection parameter for `xclip`.

Or just:

```
sh -c 'sleep 0.5; xdotool type "lorem@ipsum.com"'
```

`xclip` alone:

```
sh -c 'echo "lorem@ipsum.com" | xclip -sel clip && xclip -out -sel clip'
```

But it's a long, overpiped command (personally I don't like that).

Comment: Thanks, the xdotool works now. Is there also an xclip only solution for if I just want to write something to clipboard?

Comment: It even works with 0.1 seconds so the sleep workaround drawback is minimal.

Comment: I believe `sh -c 'echo "lorem@ipsum.com" | xclip -sel clip | xclip -out -selection clipboard'` should work, though it's a long one... combination of xdotool and xclip or xdotool alone would be better, I think.

Comment: It works perfectly, Bart! I agree that xdotools works well for my use case, plus I don't have to manually paste. But it is still great functionality that I will keep in mind for the future.

Comment: @RnRoger, I've added minor change to the `xclip` command, since with the second pipe it was outputting previous clip anyway. with `&&` operand, it outputs correct data.